# Too much work on main Thread?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, java-threads

I have a fragment that has an image and a text. my App is running very slowly and the navigation drawer takes 30 secs to slide. What am i using in the main thread? I'm declaring the `textView` and `ImageView` in the `Run()` method to be compiled in a different thread.

> Fragment Java;

```
public class headercode extends Fragment implements Runnable{

    ImageView image;
    TextView text;
    View myView;    

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);
        this.run();
        return myView;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){   
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        image = (ImageView)myView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ahmed);
        text = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.text);

    }
}
```

> my MainActivity Java OnCreate Method;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener   {   

    Button button;
    headercode header;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);    

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();    

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment) != null){

            header = new headercode();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment,header).commit();
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is very non-sense code. Use _Handler_

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `Runnable` in a thread, not use `.run()`:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(this /* the runnable */);
thread.start();
```